# How to swipe through different ionic tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigation, ionic-framework

first post ever here but would really appreciate some help or advice on this:

I am currently building a project using the ionic framework and after building a functional version I decided that having the ability to swipe between tabs to show the separate sections of the app.

I built the app using the tab template that ionic offers so each page is shown through the ion-nav-view element and is a template called through state changes declared in the app.js file (see below):

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',

      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.notes', {
      url: '/notes',
      views: {
        'tab-notes': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-notes.html',
          controller: 'noteController'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.todos', {
    url: '/todos',
    views: {
      'tab-todos': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-todos.html',
        controller: 'todoController'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.doodles', {
    url: '/doodles',
    views: {
      'tab-doodles': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-doodles.html',
      }
    }
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

What I want to know is; Is there a way I can allow the user to swipe left and right to switch between the different pages?

Is it even possible? If so, should it be when there is a need to scroll as well?

I hope this is enough detail, if not I would be happy to provide as much as I can. Thanks for listening!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I played around with the tabs template and came to the following result:

```
<ion-content on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()">
```

And in each controller you will need the corresponding functions:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {

    $scope.goForward = function () {
        var selected = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
        if (selected != -1) {
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select(selected + 1);
        }
    }

    $scope.goBack = function () {
        var selected = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
        if (selected != -1 && selected != 0) {
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select(selected - 1);
        }
    }
})
```

I don't know if this is best practice and very robust. Like I said, I just played around a little after reading the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicTabsDelegate/).

I hope I gave you an idea of how it could work.

Comment: But you wont get that ```slide``` animation when you do this.

Comment: What do you mean with slide animation? Can you give an example please?

Comment: this works but the view are jumped form one view to the other. there is no animation, by animation i mean the kind of pull animation you get when u pull the sidemenu in ionic. the next view pulls from the side and after a breakpoint snaps into the viewport..but thanks this worked

Comment: Ah I see... But this should also be possible. Like I said, it's just a proof of concept. You can elaborate it further. I am just giving you a basic idea :)

Comment: Wonderful. Someone has developed the animation?

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: Another solution could be using Ionic Slide Box in addition of tabs. One could create page navigation using slide-box (which has built-in animations) and simply add tabs as visual element at the bottom of the page. Clicking on each tab would invoke function which uses `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide()` to go to proper Slide.